# Halachik source for saying ushpizin

Tags: halacha, sources-mekorot, sukkot, hachnasat-orchim-guests

Is there any source in halacha (shulchan aruch, mishna berura etc) besides for the zohar that mentions reciting the ushpizin?

Comment: Kaf Hachaim 639:8

Comment: The Zohar is a source in Halacha? I don't think so. It's a work of Kabbalah.

Comment: Shela Mesechtas Suca 192a - Keshahu

Answer (score 2):

The קיצור ש''ע ילקוט יוסף in [דיני ישיבה בסוכה בשאר ימות החג](http://www.toratemetfreeware.com/online/f_01355_part_31.html#HtmpReportNum0016_L2) says it's customary to do so:

> **יג** נכון להביא כסא מפואר לכבוד האושפיזין, מעין דוגמא למה שמביאים בעת המילה כסא לכבוד אליהו הנביא זכור לטוב, שכתוב בזוהר הקדוש דאי לא אתקינו ליה כסא לא אתי. ולכן **נוהגים לומר הנוסח עולו אושפיזין** וכו'. ואחר שיאמר נוסח זה, יקדש מעומד, ואחר ברכת לישב בסוכה, ישב, ויברך שהחיינו, שבברכה זו הוא פוטר גם את מצות הסוכה. [כ''כ החיד''א במורה באצבע אות רפט. וכן כתב בלקט הקציר סימן לב אות ה, עמוד תסא].‏